# Only 1000 Paused and Waiting Interviews?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I'm trying to trigger about 6000 processes from Process Builder (scheduled action) depending on whether it's x many days from a due date. After triggering the 6000 through the API, I noticed I can only see 1000 through Paused and Waiting Interviews (hopefully they rest are there somewhere). I also noticed some records which should have triggered a flow not having been triggered (task wasn't created). Honestly confused here! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can have up to 50,000 flows waiting at any given time. Of those, up to 1,000 will be processed per hour. The list only shows 1,000 items, but the remainder should still be waiting. It will take a few hours for them to process. You can read more in [Limitations for Waiting Flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_considerations_design_wait.htm).

Comment: Do the 1000 from the list need to come off before the rest process? I'm concerned this is the case as the rest should have processed so far and they don't appear to have.

Comment: Do you know how items are processed? For example if my process is a scheduled action 1 day before an End Date and I trigger 6000 records. If there are records that have an End Date tomorrow, and some that have an end date 6 months from now.. could the records w/ a far out end date get queued first and hold up the others? E.g. could the 1000 I see via the UI be waiting to be processed before others?

Comment: @CerealCool The records will be processed on the correct day; the ones listed are not necessarily the first ones that will be executed.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox - I was able to confirm this as well through testing finally.